# How to use owl carousel in custom module?

Tags: 7, javascript

I am trying to call [Owl Carousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/owlcarousel) from a custom module, but despite the short description of how to do that on https://www.drupal.org/node/2412689, can't figure out.

I could use Views, but then I need to call either list of nodes or node fields, but in this case, I have several items which need to be rotated in a variable. I could put them into array if the implementation requires it.

So basically my question is:

Given a list of items in a variable (or array) how can I rotate them using the Owl Carousel module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've an array, you can print the array items one by one in wrapper `<div>` tag, and apply [Own Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#demo) to wrapper `<div>` tag (check `owl-demo` class in example below). To do this in Drupal, you can process your array in your module to create HTML, and apply JS using [`drupal_add_js()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_js/7). To print HTML you can either create a [custom block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/5587/678) and show on page or create [custom page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5469855/377342).

**Implementing in Drupal with custom module:**

```
function _owl_carousel_demo() {
  $array = array('User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3', 'User 4', 'User 5', 'User 6', 'User 7');
  $output = '<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">';
  foreach ($array as $value) {
    $output .= '<div class="item"><h1>' . $value . '</h1></div>';
  }
  $output .= '</div>';
  $output .= '<div class="customNavigation">
    <a class="btn prev">Previous</a>
    <a class="btn next">Next</a>
    <a class="btn play">Autoplay</a>
    <a class="btn stop">Stop</a>
  </div></div>';

  drupal_add_css('http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css', 'external');
  drupal_add_js('http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js', 'external');
  drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      var owl = jQuery("#owl-demo");
      owl.owlCarousel({
        items : 4,
      });
    });', 'inline');

  return $output;
}
```

**Below example shows complete HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php $array = array('User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3', 'User 4', 'User 5', 'User 6', 'User 7'); ?>
    <div id="demo">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span12">
            <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
              <?php foreach ($array as $value) : ?>
                <div class="item"><h1><?php echo $value; ?></h1></div>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="customNavigation">
              <a class="btn prev">Previous</a>
              <a class="btn next">Next</a>
              <a class="btn play">Autoplay</a>
              <a class="btn stop">Stop</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var owl = $("#owl-demo");
      owl.owlCarousel({
        items : 4, //10 items above 1000px browser width
      });
      // Custom Navigation Events
      $(".next").click(function(){
        owl.trigger('owl.next');
      })
      $(".prev").click(function(){
        owl.trigger('owl.prev');
      })
      $(".play").click(function(){
        owl.trigger('owl.play',1000);
      })
      $(".stop").click(function(){
        owl.trigger('owl.stop');
      })
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```